# No puedo hacer el deploy de una Api Spring Boot con JWT en render

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

vengo aquí porque no se adonde más recurrir, quiero hacer el deploy de una API de Spring Boot en render.

De manera local funciona correctamente, pero el inconveniente lo tengo cuando quiero subir a render, cuando establezco la conexión con GitHub, comienza a hacer el deploy, finaliza todo ok pero el resultado es failled.

Que podría hacer en ese caso?, alguien más le pasa lo mismo?.

Jan 3 08:19:48 PM  ==> Cloning from https://github.com/pruebawe/BackEndML-render-...
Jan 3 08:19:52 PM  ==> Checking out commit 38df5ade3d65393a07ddb20933cf2f818d1ff44d in branch master
Jan 3 08:19:56 PM  #1 [internal] load .dockerignore
Jan 3 08:19:56 PM  #1 transferring context: 2B done
Jan 3 08:19:56 PM  #1 DONE 0.0s
Jan 3 08:19:56 PM
Jan 3 08:19:56 PM  #2 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
Jan 3 08:19:56 PM  #2 transferring dockerfile: 206B done
Jan 3 08:19:56 PM  #2 DONE 0.0s
Jan 3 08:19:56 PM
Jan 3 08:19:56 PM  #3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jdk
Jan 3 08:19:56 PM  #3 ...
Jan 3 08:19:56 PM
Jan 3 08:19:56 PM  #4 [auth] library/amazoncorretto:pull token for registry-1.docker.io
Jan 3 08:19:56 PM  #4 DONE 0.0s
Jan 3 08:19:57 PM
Jan 3 08:19:57 PM  #3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jdk
Jan 3 08:19:57 PM  #3 DONE 0.9s
Jan 3 08:19:57 PM
Jan 3 08:19:57 PM  #5 [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jdk@sha256:5cab8451adb8a919c6799ececf2503eca84c18b9b96df47f4549ea00dde90a65
Jan 3 08:19:57 PM  #5 resolve docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jdk@sha256:5cab8451adb8a919c6799ececf2503eca84c18b9b96df47f4549ea00dde90a65 done
Jan 3 08:19:58 PM  #5 extracting sha256:ca7dd9ec2225f2385955c43b2379305acd51543c28cf1d4e94522b3d94cce3ce
Jan 3 08:19:58 PM  #5 extracting sha256:ca7dd9ec2225f2385955c43b2379305acd51543c28cf1d4e94522b3d94cce3ce 0.5s done
Jan 3 08:19:59 PM  #5 ...
Jan 3 08:19:59 PM
Jan 3 08:19:59 PM  #6 [internal] load build context
Jan 3 08:19:59 PM  #6 transferring context: 43.82MB 1.9s done
Jan 3 08:19:59 PM  #6 DONE 2.0s
Jan 3 08:19:59 PM
Jan 3 08:19:59 PM  #5 [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jdk@sha256:5cab8451adb8a919c6799ececf2503eca84c18b9b96df47f4549ea00dde90a65
Jan 3 08:20:01 PM  #5 extracting sha256:2778865ff857685f8e3b22551f6e42a3a424e5d699a69417ebda32e5eb752d02
Jan 3 08:20:04 PM  #5 extracting sha256:2778865ff857685f8e3b22551f6e42a3a424e5d699a69417ebda32e5eb752d02 2.9s done
Jan 3 08:20:04 PM  #5 DONE 6.4s
Jan 3 08:20:04 PM
Jan 3 08:20:04 PM  #7 [2/2] COPY target/ML-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ML-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Jan 3 08:20:04 PM  #7 DONE 0.1s
Jan 3 08:20:04 PM
Jan 3 08:20:04 PM  #8 exporting to oci image format
Jan 3 08:20:04 PM  #8 exporting layers
Jan 3 08:20:06 PM  #8 exporting layers 1.9s done
Jan 3 08:20:06 PM  #8 exporting manifest sha256:2201cda0a5703281432f29ff4558011188f1031e00f235ce1e3e6ec9d796833c done
Jan 3 08:20:06 PM  #8 exporting config sha256:3ed300eee92461bf04987de6bc63fa06c3fb1bd40703ddeb5237c5b2ab3f7d3a done
Jan 3 08:20:14 PM  #8 DONE 10.0s
Jan 3 08:20:14 PM
Jan 3 08:20:14 PM  #9 exporting cache
Jan 3 08:20:20 PM  #9 DONE 6.7s
Jan 3 08:20:21 PM  Pushing image to registry...
Jan 3 08:20:26 PM  DONE
Jan 3 08:21:06 PM
Jan 3 08:21:06 PM    .   ____          _            __ _ _
Jan 3 08:21:06 PM   /\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)* __  __ _ \ \ \ 

Jan 3 08:21:06 PM  ( ( )_*_ | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ 

Jan 3 08:21:06 PM   \/  __*)| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
Jan 3 08:21:06 PM    '  |****| .__|*| |*|*| |*_*, | / / / /
Jan 3 08:21:06 PM   =========|*|==============|***/=/*/*/*/
Jan 3 08:21:07 PM   :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.7)
Jan 3 08:21:07 PM
Jan 3 08:21:10 PM  2023-01-03 23:21:10.031  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.portfolio.ML.MlApplication           : Starting MlApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.17 on srv-ceq9ohsgqg42m39qnkcg-kn-00002-deployment-7448dd56c5-5stpm with PID 1 (/ML-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /)
Jan 3 08:21:10 PM  2023-01-03 23:21:10.134  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.portfolio.ML.MlApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
Jan 3 08:21:37 PM  2023-01-03 23:21:37.631  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
Jan 3 08:21:40 PM  2023-01-03 23:21:40.529  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 2501 ms. Found 6 JPA repository interfaces.
Jan 3 08:22:04 PM  2023-01-03 23:22:04.836  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
Jan 3 08:22:05 PM  2023-01-03 23:22:05.235  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
Jan 3 08:22:05 PM  2023-01-03 23:22:05.235  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.70]
Jan 3 08:22:08 PM  2023-01-03 23:22:08.231  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
Jan 3 08:22:08 PM  2023-01-03 23:22:08.231  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 56101 ms
Jan 3 08:22:15 PM  2023-01-03 23:22:15.529  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
Jan 3 08:22:17 PM  2023-01-03 23:22:17.035  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.14.Final
Jan 3 08:22:23 PM  2023-01-03 23:22:23.337  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
Jan 3 08:22:27 PM  2023-01-03 23:22:27.339  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
Jan 3 08:22:38 PM  2023-01-03 23:22:38.031  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
Jan 3 08:22:38 PM  2023-01-03 23:22:38.529  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
Jan 3 08:23:06 PM  2023-01-03 23:23:06.952  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
Jan 3 08:23:07 PM  2023-01-03 23:23:07.032  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Jan 3 08:23:40 PM  2023-01-03 23:23:40.331  WARN 1 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
Jan 3 08:23:47 PM  2023-01-03 23:23:47.729  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@581b1c08, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1c240cf2, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@5b000fe6, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3e377967, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@78b7f805, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7e1ffe70, com.portfolio.ML.Security.Jwt.JwtTokenFilter@217bf99e, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7af443a3, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7b25ab31, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@58f2466c, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@16c1519e, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@61db86bf, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@193bb809]
Jan 3 08:23:54 PM  2023-01-03 23:23:54.335  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
Jan 3 08:23:54 PM  2023-01-03 23:23:54.729  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.portfolio.ML.MlApplication           : Started MlApplication in 183.817 seconds (JVM running for 200.471)
Jan 3 08:26:01 PM  2023-01-03 23:26:01.836  INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Jan 3 08:26:02 PM  2023-01-03 23:26:02.031  INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
Jan 3 08:26:06 PM  2023-01-03 23:26:06.288  INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Mi problema es que no puedo subir la Api a render, siendo que todo sale ok.